# how to save a distressed text effect logo for print with a dark background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, export

I designed that distressed text effect logo in Adobe Illustrator CC, I know how to save it for web as PNG 24 with transparent background, so it can be used later on any background color. But I don't know how to save it for print, I generally save as PDF with no background for print use, but how do I save that one ?[image: logo]

That is how it looks on a white background[image: logo on white background]

Comment: Will the paper color be black?

Comment: @WELZ I really don't know, if it was black then the PDF should be exactly like the image above.  But the real question is can it be printed on white,because I don't think it will be obvious, so Should  I save the PDF with the background ?

Comment: You can't merely change the light fills to dark fills?

Comment: Maybe now I get it @Scott, you mean I will change the text fill to black and do the same effect and save as PDF. I think you are right, that's the way it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the light fills to dark fills.**

If you have white artwork on black....

[image]

In order for the artwork to have the same impact on a white background, you *reverse* the artwork...

[image]

If the intent is to print this on a dark colored stock (paper), you would still reverse the artwork this way. Then the **press** would use a light colored *ink* when printed. The artwork should be black to indicate *where* ink is to be printed. The actual color of the print is determined by what color the pressman puts in the printing press.

Without more detail about the overall artwork to be printed this is merely a general guideline.

I would, personally, suggest that you *not* "design logos" on black backgrounds. The use cases for a reversed (light on dark) logo are small. Designing a logo on a white background is typically best because I think you get a better feel for how the artwork will appear in 95% of its use.

Comment: I think that is extremely helpful. so in all cases it should be black. Can't thank you enough ! @Scott